# Magento2 : Update translation using API response

Tags: api, localisation, magento-2.1.9

**I want to know how to update some translation through Magento 2.1.9 REST API.**

For example, when I add a configurable product in the cart thanks to the Magento 2.1.9 REST API, if the user do not select an option, the default error message response is `You need to choose options for your item.`

Which is translated here `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/i18n/en_US.csv:30`

And trigger here : `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php:1095`

I want to update the default translation, but I do not find a way to solve it, I try :

- I added the updated translation in my theme : `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv:5` but it seems that the theme is not load in the API mode
- I forced the current area and store with `$this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);`

Without success.

I do not find any resource how to translate through API area.

I prefer keep all the translation in Magento and not delegate this to the frontend application.

All ideas are appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I just found a workaround.

You need to emulate the correct store with the frontend area, and **then reload the translation data** :

```
// Emulate store frontend
$storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

$this->translator->loadData(null, true);
echo __('your text to translate');
$this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```

But it is just a workaround for custom API where you manage the result, not for native Magento API.

Let me know if there is a proper way to manage this.

Does language packages can solve my problem ?

Comment: You can added a store code in the API URL, So it'll translate content based on the store view locale. Eg : `en` is store code, http://yourdomain.com/en/rest/V1/your/url

Comment: It is not the problem, the content is already translated correctly from magento native translation file. The question is how to overwride the default translation.

Comment: Create a new language pack and extend vendor("en_US") language pack. Refer this [link] (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#m2devgde-xlate-inheritancework). So you dont need to emulate the frontend in API.

Comment: Ok I will try this, do not hesitate to answer to have a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

> I think in API request, system will not load any theme related stuffs(style, locale, etc).

So you can create a new language pack and extend the vendor language.
Refer this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#m2devgde-xlate-inheritancework)

**language.xml**

```
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>en_US</code>
    <vendor>your</vendor>
    <package>language_pack</package>
    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    <use vendor="Magento" package="en_US"/>
</language>
```

**Magento 2.1.9** : [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.9/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Translate.php#L179-L182)

Theme locale will get overridden by the language pack.

```
    $this->_loadModuleTranslation();
    $this->_loadThemeTranslation();
    $this->_loadPackTranslation();
    $this->_loadDbTranslation();
```

**Magento 2.2** : [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Translate.php#L184-L187)

theme locale will not get overridden by the language pack.

```
    $this->_loadModuleTranslation();
    $this->_loadPackTranslation();
    $this->_loadThemeTranslation();
    $this->_loadDbTranslation();
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you describe just a little more the steps to extend the us_en default language pack.

Comment: @Franck refer this Magento doc link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#m2devgde-xlate-inheritancework they have explained how to create a new language pack and extending another language pack.